# Manage deployments using the Kubernetes REST API

Tags: kubernetes

I need to delete a kubernetes deployment resource using REST API. That's possible and it works, but I just found out that while the deployment resource is deleted ok, its associated ReplicaSet is not.

That means its pods are still running.

I don't know how to find name of a ReplicaSet associated to a Deployment.

I can see it when using kubectl: *kubectl describe deployment mydeployment*, but I can't find a REST method to get that information.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An easy way to find the calls associated would be to use the associated `kubectl` command with a higher level of verbosity (`--v=6` or `--v=9`).

```
#~ kubectl delete deployment nginx-deployment --v=6
I1201 12:26:16.511683    6235 round_trippers.go:318] GET https://XXX/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/deployments/nginx-deployment 200 OK in 50 milliseconds
I1201 12:26:16.568980    6235 round_trippers.go:318] PUT https://XXX/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/deployments/nginx-deployment 200 OK in 50 milliseconds
I1201 12:26:17.621751    6235 round_trippers.go:318] GET https://XXX/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/deployments/nginx-deployment 200 OK in 50 milliseconds
I1201 12:26:17.680228    6235 round_trippers.go:318] GET https://XXX/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/replicasets?labelSelector=app%3Dnginx 200 OK in 50 milliseconds
I1201 12:26:17.738684    6235 round_trippers.go:318] GET https://XXX/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/replicasets/nginx-deployment-4087004473 200 OK in 56 milliseconds
I1201 12:26:18.790243    6235 round_trippers.go:318] GET https://XXX/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/replicasets/nginx-deployment-4087004473 200 OK in 49 milliseconds
I1201 12:26:18.843446    6235 round_trippers.go:318] PUT https://XXX/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/replicasets/nginx-deployment-4087004473 200 OK in 50 milliseconds
I1201 12:26:18.894538    6235 round_trippers.go:318] GET https://XXX/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/replicasets/nginx-deployment-4087004473 200 OK in 49 milliseconds
I1201 12:26:19.946417    6235 round_trippers.go:318] GET https://XXX/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/replicasets/nginx-deployment-4087004473 200 OK in 49 milliseconds
I1201 12:26:20.001367    6235 round_trippers.go:318] DELETE https://XXX/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/replicasets/nginx-deployment-4087004473 200 OK in 53 milliseconds
I1201 12:26:20.055669    6235 round_trippers.go:318] DELETE https://XXX/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/deployments/nginx-deployment 200 OK in 53 milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You pointed that you wanted to find the replica set in the above question. You can find the replica set by

`kubectl get rs -n deployment-namespace`

rs:- replicaset